# Бесконечный перебор массива

Tags: javascript

Дан цикл с большим количеством итераций. Дан массив с четырьмя элементами.
Как красиво реализовать циклический перебор массива внутри цикла так:

0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9

0|1|2|3|0|1|2|3|0|1 и тд

Наверху итерации цикла, внизу элементы массива.

Comment: `indexInArray = indexInLoop % 4`

Answer (score 1):

В новой спецификации `js` есть такое понятие, как генераторы, можно использовать их для поддержки старыми браузерами использовать [полифил](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-regenerator/)

Пример

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const generator = function* (arr) {
    let i = 0
    let length = arr.length
    while(true) {
        yield arr[i]
        i++
        if(i === length) i = 0
    }
}

// используем
const arrayLoop = generator(array)
for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    console.log(arrayLoop.next())
    // next будет возвращать объект типа
    // {value, done}
    // где вам нужно value
}
```

[image: Примерный ответ]

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4
let count = 0;
while(true) {
  for(el of arr) {
    console.log(el)
    count++
  }
}
```

Сделайте его асинхронным и с таймером, или будет очень большая нагрузка.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже мучает подобный вопрос. А точнее, есть подобная задача, и есть необходимость сделать её максимально быстрой. При чём не просто в каком-то цикле, а по возникновению событий... 
Например, есть 4 воркера и нужно по-очереди каждому выдавать задачу на обработку.
Не уверен, что это правильно, но делаю это как-то так:

```
'use strict';

const Counter = function (array) {
    if(Array.isArray(array)){
        this.current = -1;
        this.length = array.length;
    }
    else {
        throw new Error(`Can't create instance, non-array value passed.`);
    }
    this.next=function(){
        this.current+=1;
        if(this.current>=this.length) this.current=0;
        return this.current;
    };
    return this;
};

let workers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
let nextWorker = new Counter(workers);


for(let i=0; i<100; i++){
    console.log(workers[nextWorker.next()]);
}
```

Но, допустим это коряво и зачем для этого вообще создавать класс...
Но можно или просто выделить под нужные массивы переменную с длинной... Или расширить прототип Array и добавить в него функционал итератора,только... немножко быстрее, а главное - бесконечного...

```
Array.prototype.next = function () {
    if(Array.isArray(this) && !this.firstInterationPass){
        this.currentElement = -1;
        this.firstInterationPass = true;
    }
    this.currentElement+=1;
    if(this.currentElement>=this.length) this.currentElement=0;
    return this[this.currentElement];
};

let workers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];


for(let i=0; i<100; i++){
    console.log(workers.next());
}
```

Как вы догадываетесь, вызов

> worker.next()

Вернет значение следующего элемента массива.
И код выведет 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2...